# How to dump all of addresses from wallet.dat for other alt-coins?

Tags: private-key, wallet.dat, solo-mining, altcoin

I'm on [binarycoin](https://cryptocointalk.com/topic/2432-binarycoin-bic-information/) now, with solo mining. Luck smile to me. I'm found 5 blocks. It is 100.0 binarycoins.

I'm trying to use "aggressive" speed-up, my daemon compiled with `-O3`.

After last block I caught crash of daemon. And fails of relaunching with err:

```
Database environment corrupt; the wrong log files may have been removed or incompatible database files imported from another environment 
PANIC: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery 
wallet.dat: unable to flush page: 19 
txn_checkpoint: failed to flush the buffer cache: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
```

If I'm redownload the blockchain.

`-rescan` doesn't help.

I'm shutdown the network, clean everything in the .binarycoin/* except `wallet.dat` and `binarycoin.conf`. Launch the daemon. My `wallet.dat` remembered that there were blocks, every block was marked as `orphan`. I've start to sniffing for my coins. My account named as `""` contain only one address. I've found a web-blockchain  www.binarycoin.info:8080/ 
There was no my address.

By `tx ids` in my `wallet.dat`, on this web-blockchain I've found addresses that received the bounties. I've dumped privkeys of this addresses, and cooled down.

---

My nerve continue playing. What if there is no side web-blockchain. How should I discovery the `tx ids` and thereafter `my addresses`, and thereafter dump my `privkeys`?

There is no option to get every address from `wallet.dat`, only one (default) address.

I found [pywallet](https://github.com/joric/pywallet). It is for `Bitcoin`. Nevertheless, I've dump in plain-text my `wallet.dat`. 117 addresses with their privkeys.

I compare my `real addresses` with this 117. No one.

I compare `privkeys`. No one.

How to trully extract all addresses and all `privkeys` that wallet.dat contains? 
( Specially for alt-coins )

Answer (score 4):

now you can use `bitcoin-cli dumpwallet` command to export all your privkeys

Answer (score 2):

You can get all of this info from the bitcoind API.
you download bitcoind, set your RPC configurations into your .conf and then connect via RPC

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

http://paste.ee/p/IBU79

The same applies for all the coins really. Most just copy the bitcoin or litecoin source. Many of the features are the same,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping backup copies of all the data you have, and not give up on the idea that you will *eventually* be able to extract the private keys from that data, even if you can't find a program that works right now.

Presumably you have records of when your computer generated blocks. You should be able to find matching records from the public blockchain site (if there is one) for your altcoin. Your question suggests that your wallet software thinks the blocks are orphans, which is a bad sign. I wouldn't trust that yet. If the blockchain site shows orphan blocks, and you find your blocks listed there as orphans, then probably there is no hope. If you find the blocks listed as part of the official chain, then you can get the public address the mining fees were paid to from that.

Someone, maybe only the developer of the coin, knows how to find the matching private keys in your wallet. If you cannot find a solution yourself, wait and see if the value of the coins becomes high enough to hire professional help. In the meantime, you can look at the bitcoin code and possibly at the changes made to produce binarycoin, and probably you can figure out how to extract the private keys from the original wallet.dat file, the wallet.bak file, or earlier backups of these which contain your blocks.

I wish you the best. Unfortunately some have to learn the hard way that there is a reason for paying banks to secure our money.